# javascript regex - look behind alternative?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a regex that works fine in most regex implementations:

```
(?<!filename)\.js$
```

This matches .js for a string which ends with .js except for filename.js

Javascript doesn't have regex lookbehind. Is anyone able put together an alternative regex which achieve the same result and works in javascript?

Here are some thoughts, but needs helper functions. I was hoping to achieve it just with a regex:
http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: if you just need to check a specific filename or list of filenames, why not just use two checks?  check if it ends in .js and then if it does, check that it doesn't match filename.js or vice versa.

Comment: Update: The latest public Chrome version (v62) includes (presumably experimental) lookbehinds out of the box :D
Note however that lookbehinds are still in proposal stage 3: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind . So, it may take a while until JavaScript everywhere supports it. Better be careful about using in production!

Comment: # Update: ES2018 includes [lookbehind assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) [Plus](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-regexp-proposals): - dotAll mode (the s flag)
- Lookbehind assertions
- Named capture groups
- Unicode property escapes

Comment: Just use **`(?<=thingy)thingy`** for _positive lookbehind_ and **`(?<!thingy)thingy`** for _negative lookbehind_. **Now it supports them.**

Comment: @K._ As of Feb 2018 **that's not true** yet!! And it will need some time because browsers and engines must implement the specification (current in draft).

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Yes, you're right. The **proposal** is currently on _Stage 4_. Maybe I was thinking of only _Chrome_, I guess.

Comment: nodejs http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/ supports it

Comment: Firefox still hasn't implemented the 2018 specification  which prescribes support for look-behinds. Here's the [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665).

Comment: @LonnieBest meanwhile fixed for FF ([5 days ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665#c35)) :-)

Comment: @Wolf : That's fantastic news. When will it land? Version 77?

Comment: looks [like 78](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1634135) (see ` Milestone:
mozilla78`)

Comment: Still not supported for safari @ 2022

Comment: As of Jan 12, The latest Safari Technology Preview release 161 (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174931#c56) supports lookbehind.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`^(?!filename).+\.js` works for me

tested against:

- test.js match
- blabla.js match
- filename.js no match

A proper explanation for this regex can be found at [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Look ahead is available since [version 1.5 of javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions) and is supported by all major browsers

**Updated** to match filename2.js and 2filename.js but not filename.js

`(^(?!filename\.js$).).+\.js`

Comment: That question you linked to talks about a slightly different problem: matching a string that doesn't contain the target word *anywhere*.  This one is much simpler: matching a string that doesn't *start with* the target word.

Comment: Thats really nice, it only misses out on cases like: filename2.js or filenameddk.js or similar. This is a no match, but should be a match.

Comment: @daniel You asked for a look-behind, not a look-ahead, why did you accepted this answer?

Comment: I'm grave-digging here, but the updated one has a broken/useless capture group and matches "filename.js" in the string "filename.json". It should be `^(?!filename\.js$).+\.js$`

Comment: the given one does not match on `a.js`

Comment: The original regex with lookbehind doesn't match `2filename.js`, but the regex given here does. A more appropriate one would be `^(?!.*filename\.js$).*\.js$`. This means, match any `*.js` *except* `*filename.js`.

Answer (score 169):

EDIT: From ECMAScript 2018 onwards, [lookbehind assertions (even unbounded) are supported natively](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind).

In previous versions, you can do this:

```
^(?:(?!filename\.js$).)*\.js$
```

This does explicitly what the lookbehind expression is doing implicitly: check each character of the string if the lookbehind expression plus the regex after it will not match, and only then allow that character to match.

```
^                 # Start of string
(?:               # Try to match the following:
 (?!              # First assert that we can't match the following:
  filename\.js    # filename.js 
  $               # and end-of-string
 )                # End of negative lookahead
 .                # Match any character
)*                # Repeat as needed
\.js              # Match .js
$                 # End of string
```

Another edit:

It pains me to say (especially since this answer has been upvoted so much) that there is a far easier way to accomplish this goal. There is no need to check the lookahead at every character:

```
^(?!.*filename\.js$).*\.js$
```

works just as well:

```
^                 # Start of string
(?!               # Assert that we can't match the following:
 .*               # any string, 
  filename\.js    # followed by filename.js
  $               # and end-of-string
)                 # End of negative lookahead
.*                # Match any string
\.js              # Match .js
$                 # End of string
```

Comment: Works on lots of cases except where there are preceeding characters, for example: filename.js (works-nomatch) filename2.js (works-match) blah.js (works - match) 2filename.js (doesn't work - nomatch) --- having said that, the lookbehind has the same limitation which I didn't realise until now...

Comment: @daniel: Well, your regex (with lookbehind) also doesn't match `2filename.js`. My regex matches in exactly the same cases as your example regex.

Comment: Forgive my naivety but is there a use for the non capturing group here? I've always known that to be only useful when trying to glean back reference for replacement in a string. As far as I know, this too will work ^(?!filename\.js$).*\.js$

Comment: Not quite, that regex checks for "filename.js" only at the start of the string. But `^(?!.*filename\.js$).*\.js$` would work. Trying to think of situations where the ncgroup might still be necessary...

Comment: This approach can be summarized as: instead of looking behind X, look ahead at every character that comes before X?

Comment: @HaiPhan: Yes, but re-reading my answer I just noticed that there is a vastly less complicated solution that I had completely overlooked. Will update my answer X-)

Comment: [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665) still doesn't support look-behinds as prescribed by the 2018 specification. I understand they're actively working on it though.

Comment: BTW, I really like how you break the RegEx apart and describe it so concisely.

Comment: Really appreciate the breakdown of what each component does. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Let's suppose you want to find all `int` not preceded by `unsigned`:

With support for negative look-behind:

```
(?<!unsigned )int
```

Without support for negative look-behind:

```
((?!unsigned ).{9}|^.{0,8})int
```

Basically idea is to grab n preceding characters and exclude match with negative look-ahead, but also match the cases where there's no preceeding n characters. (where n is length of look-behind).

So the regex in question:

```
(?<!filename)\.js$
```

would translate to:

```
((?!filename).{8}|^.{0,7})\.js$
```

You might need to play with capturing groups to find exact spot of the string that interests you or you want't to replace specific part with something else.

Comment: I just converted this: `(?<!barna)(?<!ene)(?<!en)(?<!erne) (?:sin|vår)e?(?:$| (?!egen|egne))` to `(?!barna).(?!erne).(?!ene).(?!en).. (?:sin|vår)e?(?:$| (?!egen|egne))` which does the trick for my needs. Just providing this as another "real-world" scenario. See [link](https://regex101.com/r/wL8nS7/5)

Comment: I think you meant: `((?!unsigned ).{9}|^.{0,8})int`

Comment: @pansay Yes. Thank you. I just corrected my response.

Comment: Thanks for the more generalized answer which works even where there is a need to match deep within the text (where initial ^ would be impractical)!

Answer (score 3):

If you can look ahead but back, you could reverse the string first and then do a lookahead. Some more work will need to be done, of course.

Comment: This answer could really use some improvement.  It seems more like a comment to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is an equivalent solution to [Tim Pietzcker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7376612/4747193) (see also comments of same answer):

```
^(?!.*filename\.js$).*\.js$
```

It means, match `*.js` except `*filename.js`.

To get to this solution, you can check which patterns the negative lookbehind excludes, and then exclude exactly these patterns with a negative lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers from Tim Pietzcker and other persons. I was so inspired by their works. However, there is no any ideal solution, I think, for mimicking lookbehind. For example, solution from Pietzcker is limited by `$` as EOL, that is, without `$` there would get unexpected result:

```js
let str="filename.js  main.js  2022.07.01"
console.log( /^(?!.*filename\.js).*\.js/g.exec(str) ) //null
```

Another limitation is that it is hard to translate multiply lookbehinds, such as:

```js
let reg=/(?<!exP0)exp0 \d (?<!exP1)exp1 \d (?<!exP2)exp2/
```

How to build a more **generic and free** method to use lookbehind assertion alternatively? Bellow is my solution.

The core pattern of alternative code is:

```js
(?:(?!ExpB)....|^.{0,3})ExpA <= (?<!ExpB)ExpA
```

Detail explanation:

```bash
(?:         # start an unsave group:
 (?!ExpB)   # Assert a possion who can't match the ExpB
 ....       # Any string, the same length as ExpB
 |^.{0,3}   # Or match any string whoes length is less than ExpB
)           # End of negative lookahead
ExpA        # Match ExpA
```

For instance:

```js
var str="file.js  main.js  2022.07.01"
var reg=/(?:(?!file)....|^.{0,3})\.js/g // <= (?<!file)\.js
console.log( reg.exec(str)[0] )  // main.js
```

Here is an implement to translate above pattern into a sugar:

```js
var str="file.js  main.js  2022.07.01"
var reg=newReg("﹤4?!file﹥\\.js","g") //pattern sugar
console.log(reg.exec(str)[0]) // main.js

function newReg(sReg,flags){
  flags=flags||""
  sReg=sReg.replace(/(^|[^\\])\\﹤/g,"$1<_sl_>").replace(/(^|[^\\])\\﹥/g,"$1<_sr_>")
  if (/﹤\?<?([=!])(.+?)﹥/.test(sReg)){
    throw "invalid format of string for lookbehind regExp"
  }
  var reg=/﹤(\d+)\?<?([=!])(.+?)﹥/g
  if (sReg.match(reg)){
    sReg=sReg.replace(reg, function(p0,p1,p2,p3){
      return "(?:(?"+p2+p3+")"+".".repeat(parseInt(p1))+"|^.{0,"+(parseInt(p1)-1)+"})"
    })
  }
  sReg=sReg.replace(/<_sl_>/g,"﹤").replace(/<_sr_>/g,"﹥")
  var rr=new RegExp(sReg,flags)
  return rr
}
```

Two special characters  `﹤`( `\uFE64 or &#65124;` ) and `﹥` ( `\uFE65 or &#65125;` )  are used to enclose the lookbehind expression, and a number `N` counting the length of lookbehind expression must follow the `﹤`. That is ,the syntax of lookbehind is:

```js
﹤N?!ExpB﹥ExpA <= (?<!ExpB)ExpA
﹤N?=ExpB﹥ExpA <= (?<=ExpB)ExpA
```

To make the pattern above more ES5-like, you can replace `﹤` or `﹥` with parenthesis and remove `N` , by writing more code into `newReg()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is not tackling really how to rewrite a regex to simulate lookbehinds, but i managed to overcome some very simple situations like this one by replacing the unwanted match from the string beforehand, as in:

```
  let string = originalString.replace("filename.js", "filename_js")
  string.match(/.*\.js/)
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is a positive lookbehind JavaScript alternative showing how to capture the last name of people with 'Michael' as their first name.

1) Given this text:

```
const exampleText = "Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green Miller and Michael Wood?";
```

get an array of last names of people named Michael.
The result should be: `["Jordan","Johnson","Green","Wood"]`

2) Solution:

```
function getMichaelLastName2(text) {
  return text
    .match(/(?:Michael )([A-Z][a-z]+)/g)
    .map(person => person.slice(person.indexOf(' ')+1));
}

// or even
    .map(person => person.slice(8)); // since we know the length of "Michael "
```

3) Check solution

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(    getMichaelLastName(exampleText)    ));
// ["Jordan","Johnson","Green","Wood"]
```

Demo here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/GjwRoo

You can also try it out by running the snippet below.

```js
const inputText = "Michael, how are you? - Cool, how is John Williamns and Michael Jordan? I don't know but Michael Johnson is fine. Michael do you still score points with LeBron James, Michael Green Miller and Michael Wood?";



function getMichaelLastName(text) {
  return text
    .match(/(?:Michael )([A-Z][a-z]+)/g)
    .map(person => person.slice(8));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(    getMichaelLastName(inputText)    ));
```