# javascript, replace \n with \r\n

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all `\n` with `\r\n`, but only if `\n` hasn't already `\r` previosly.
i.e.
`Hello\nGreat\nWorld` -> `Hello\r\nGreat\r\nWorld`
`Hello\r\nGreat\r\nWorld` -> `Hello\r\nGreat\r\nWorld`.

In Java i can do it in next way

```
"Hello\nGreat\nWorld".replaceAll("(?<!\r)\n", "\r\n");
```

But `(?<!X)` construct is absent in JS.
Any ideas, how can I do it in JS?

Comment: just replace all `\r\n` by `\n`, after that all `\n` by `\r\n`. No fancy regex needed.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply make the `\r` an optional part of the match, then you can replace with impunity:

```
"Hello\r\nWorld\n".replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n")
```

Comment: @Jack: I saw all that and was currently thinking "that happens to me all the time too" :)

Answer (score 7):

```
str.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\n', '\r\n')
```