# Capture words not followed by symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capture all (english) words except abbreviations whose pattern are:

```
"_any-word-symbols-including-dash."
```

(so there is underscore in the beginning and dot in the end an any letters and dash in the middle)

I tried smthing like this:

```
/\b([A-Za-z-^]+)\b[^\.]/g
```

but i seems that I don't understand how to work with negative matches.

**UPDATE:**

I need not just to match but wrap the words in some tags:

"a some words _abbr-abrr. a here" I should get:

```
<w>a</w> <w>some</w> <w>words</w> _abbr-abbr. <w>a</w> <w>here</w>
```

So I need to use replace with correct regex:

```
test.replace(/correct regex/, '<w>$1</w>')
```

Comment: What is your expected result with your string?

Comment: Useful tool for testing RegEx: http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: @Anton Thanks for the link, fine tool, before I used another for testing.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR If you found a solution, you are encouraged to post it as an answer and accept it to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is `(?!)`.

So you can use:

```
/\b([^_\s]\w*(?!\.))\b/g
```

Unfortunately, there is [no lookbehind in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7376238/2454376), so you can't do similar trick with "not prefixed by `_`".

Example:

```
> a = "a some words _abbr. a here"
> a.replace(/\b([^_\s]\w*(?!\.))\b/g, "<w>$1</w>")
"<w>a</w> <w>some</w> <w>words</w> _abbr. <w>a</w> <w>here</w>"
```

Following your comment with `-`. Updated regex is:

```
/\b([^_\s\-][\w\-]*(?!\.))\b/g

> "abc _abc-abc. abc".replace(/\b([^_\s\-][\w\-]*(?!\.))\b/g, "<w>$1</w>")
"<w>abc</w> _abc-abc. <w>abc</w>"
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work beter, the problem i can not resolve with abbreviations that contain dash like "_abbr-abbr", can you help?

Comment: Ah, ok)) I just forget to put a dot when was testing abbrs with dash) Thank you again for the solution.