# Regex Positive Lookbehind on url segment

Tags: javascript, regex

I am parsing a number from a URL string. The URL looks like:

https://www.myapi.com/player/?url=https%3A//myapi.com/users/11468859&color=788b78&auto_play=false&show_artwork=false

I would like to match the number between 'users/' and '&'. In this case '11468859'. So I using a positive lookahead and lookbehind to accomplish this.

This is what I have so far:

```
(?<=users/)([0-9]*?)(?=\&)
```

This doesn't match anything. My lookbehind is wrong. So if I omit the lookbehind I can match on `users/11468859`

```
([0-9]*?)(?=\&) matches >> 'users/11468859'
```

How do I correctly create a positive lookbehind to match on `users/`?

Thanks!

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: I had to add a `\ ` before the `/` in `users/`, but your regex (`(?<=users\/)([0-9]*?)(?=\&)`) worked (PCRE flavor): http://regex101.com/r/rP6sH3

Comment: I was testing this in a regex tester located here:http://regexpal.com/ Ultimately this expression will be in JS code. I will test it in the REPL tool to make sure the test tool is not giving me bad results

Comment: Even `'(?<=users/)[0-9]+'` would suffice.

Comment: Moreover, if your regex engine supports PCRE then your regex should work.

Comment: JavaScript regexes do **not** support lookbehind.

Comment: @acdcjunior oh really?! That would explain it.

Comment: Yes. Take that link I showed ( http://regex101.com/r/rP6sH3 ) change the combo above from "PCRE (PHP)" to "JavaScript", you'll see it stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting aside your lookbehind question for a moment, this regex works:

```
users/([0-9]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-a--VkcQPYncxze5)

The id is in capture group one.

In debuggex your lookbehind works fine but not in JavaScript:

```
(?<=users/)([0-9]*?)(?=\&)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IroGKEC7AX1Vpavy)

(You could also get away with just

```
(?<=users/)([0-9]*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7seIoDmGOOcVUrG8)

since `[0-9]*` is [greedy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).)

However, as you're using JavaScript, I recommend the regex at the top of my answer.

Comment: Wow...Debuggex...sweet. Thanks for sharing! The only problem with the first regex is that it will match `user/`, and I assume he's using lookbehind/ahead because he doesn't want to match it. Excellent answer, though.

Comment: @muppetjones, my stackoverflow Muppet buddy: How will it match `user/`? It's explicitly `users/`.

Comment: Yeah. That Debuggex is pretty rad. Thanks!

Comment: The lookbehind matches, but doesn't return those matched characters as a part of the actual match, which could be relevant. Without the lookbehind, `users/` actually matches as a part of the regex.

Comment: I see. Without the possibility of lookbehinds in JavaScript, I don't see another option. The ID is separately captured, so it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that the desired segment will be a series of integers immediately after `user/`, you don't need the look ahead. Also, I would recommend escaping any sort of slash: `\/`

```
(?<=users\/)([0-9]*?)
```

Also, you don't need to tell the regex not to be greedy unless you know it will run into other numbers, and I would consider telling the regex that there *must* be numbers so it won't match if they are missing:

thus

```
([0-9]*?)
```

becomes

```
(\d+)
```

Comment: I didn't even read your answer. If I could, I'd give you +2 for your name and for your profile pic!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches avaiable in most languages. To match a number use the positive look ahead fromat (?<=STUFF). To match numbers try \d+ or [0-9]+. Each of the following lines work. The second includes a positive look ahead for including letters in an id but will fail if the ampersand is moved.

```
(?<=users.)\d+
(?<=users.).*?(?=&)
(?<=users.)[0-9]+
```

For more information: http://myregextester.com/index.php#highlighttab

Answer (score 0):

> How do I correctly create a positive lookbehind to match on users/?

You don't, because JavaScript does not support lookbehinds:

From [javascript regex - look behind alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative):

> Javascript doesn't have regex lookbehind.

http://regexadvice.com/forums/thread/58678.aspx:

> The JavaScript regex engine does not support look-behinds

As an alternative, you can capture the number like this:

```
users\/(.*?)\&
```

And just access the first capturing group. Explanation and demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/aZ3bL0

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string = "https://www.myapi.com/player/?url=https%3A//myapi.com/users/11468859&color=788b78&auto_play=false&show_artwork=false"
regex = /users.([\d]*)/;
arr = regex.exec(a);
result = arr[1];
```