# Using Javascript non-capturing group in a replace

Tags: javascript, regex

The expression

```
"abcb".replace(/(?:a)b/, 'x')
```

returns "xcb".  What I want it return is "axcb"; that is, the "a" is not captured.

Is this possible in a single regex?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your intention but how about `"abcd".replace(/ab/, 'ax')`?

Comment: Seriously - That is the whole point of a **non**-capturing group. This question is weird (sorry if my comment isn't constructive). Can you change the pattern?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative

Comment: ["non-capturing" is with regard to remembering the match for subexpressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk)

Comment: The question should be clarified in regards of what shall be achieved. You desired result can also be obtained via '"abcd".replace(/b/, 'x')'

Comment: @SGD -- I want to replace "b" if and only if it is preceded by an "a".

Comment: @collapsar -- in the actual problem, the RE I want to not capture is more complicate than "a".  anubhava's suggestion would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it capturing:

```
"abcd".replace(/(a)b/, '$1x')
//=> axcd
```