# Domain name validation that can't start with www

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a RegEx for domain name validation that shouldn't allow http:// or www at the start (i.e. msft.com, google.com,amazon.com, etc.). I've found plenty of posts on this site and the closest came with this solution:

```
^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$
```

This won't allow http:// but it will allow me to enter www.google.com. How can I adjust this?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Just an FYI the [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex is not supported in JavaScript so I'm not sure if the `<!-` will work.

Comment: You're exactly right. It's not working with JS.

Comment: Might be a useful take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `^` with `^(?!www\.)`:

```
^(?!www\.)((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$
```

This just means that the start of the string (`^`) cannot be followed by `www.`.