# Match the second word with no specific word behind

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a follow-up of:
[javascript regex - look behind alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative/35658504?noredirect=1#comment58998520_35658504)

In my situation, I'm looking to only match the second word when there is no specific word that preceeds the term. As with the prior issue I need a solution that doesn't utilize the look behind technique.

I'm looking to exclude mentions such as the following:

```
patient has a history of pulmonary edema
```

Using the expression:

```
((?!pulmonary ).{10})\bedema
```

But given the following sentence:

```
Continuing dyspnea and lower-extremity edema
```

I would like the match to only return `edema` instead of `extremity edema`.

Comment: [What about this regex](https://regex101.com/r/hI1yZ8/2). Would that behave  like expected? Match in group 1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Apparently, regexpal and my javascript behave similarly and treat the entire line as a match in the last case "Continuing dyspnea and lower-extremity edema"

Comment: Did you [check/access the first group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) See [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1LL57c7h/)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this pattern:

```
(?!pulmonary).{10}\b(edema)\b
```

The demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/hI1yZ8/3).

Comment: I may not be asking this very clearly.  I am matching `extremity edema`, but what I want to match is only `edema' in the following:                                               _Continuing dyspnea and lower-extremity edema_                                                The criteria for excluding the term 'edema' has it's corresponding 9 character offset included (e.g. `123456789 edema`) but I want to drop the first word in what is returned as a pattern (e.g. no '123456789' included)

Comment: Apologies for the poor editing as my time limit ran out to fix.

Comment: The match it gives is only `edema`. (?!pulmonary) is a 'Negative Lookahead', not a ' look behind technique'. The 'look behind technique' looks like `(?<=...)` or `(?<!...)`.

Comment: Agreed.  As with the original poster had requested is that the method be an alternative to the 'look behind' technique.  Apparently, javascript does allow the latter.

Comment: The limitation was only experienced in the Regexpal utility as `(?<!pulmonary).\b(edema)\b` worked perfectly fine in the code.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SeanMurphy: Please take a look at [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/hI1yZ8/5), which leaves out `1234567890 edema`.