# What is a good regex to match any file name that ends with `.js` but not '.bin.js'

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I want to match the following:

- file1.js
- file2.src.js
- file3.bin.src.js
- file1.binbin.js
- file1.in.js
- file1.b.js

But not:

- file1.bin.js
- file2.src.bin.js

I have the following solutions so far:

- `^(?!.+\.bin\.js$).+\.js$` https://regex101.com/r/iR6yC9/1. The problem with this approach is `.+` as well as `.js$` is spelled out twice, so it feels a bit verbose and redundant.
- `^(?:(?!\.bin\.js$).)+\.js$` https://regex101.com/r/zQ1kE0/1. The problem with the 2nd approach is that the look ahead inside the non-capturing group makes it less readable, although it does 'reuse' the `.+`

I feel both solutions are not ideal. I wonder if there's a good regex to solve this problem that is more readable, less redundant

Comment: You need to use negative lookbehind, but Javascript doesn't have it.

Comment: I think your 'problem' of repeating parts such as ".js" is a non-issue. Is is easier to read and probably faster than alternative expressions.

Answer (score 2):

If Javascript had negative lookbehind, that would be the way to do it. Since it doesn't, the most readable solution (IMHO) is to use two regular expressions.

```
if (/\.js$/.test(filename) && !/\.bin\.js$/.test(filename))
```

If you can do it in another language that has negative lookbehind, it would be:

```
/(?<!\.bin)\.js$/
```

If you read [javascript regex - look behind alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative) you'll see that your original expression is one of the common workarounds for this missing feature.

Comment: Thanks. Two regex is not an option for me unfortunately. What would be a good solution using negative lookbehind supposing I am not using JavaScript?

Comment: @LiangZhou Why isn't it an option? What aren't you telling us?

Comment: @DaveNewton, because I don't own the code so I can't change the logic. The regex is configurable so I can change. The logic is currently taking a configurable regex and test against file names. So it has to be one regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of regex is counterintuitive at first until you've had to wrangle similar ones a few times, then it makes sense but takes a bit of fiddling.

Anyway this should do the trick.

```
/.*(?:[^n]|[^i]n|[^b]in|[^.]bin)\.js$/
```

Try it out [on rgex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zG2hI7/2)

Comment: This should do the trick of being "more readable, less redundant"? ^^ Small issue: it matches `bla.js\n.js` - apart from that it is probably as good as it gets...

Comment: No it just looks redundant. You have filenames with literal newlines in them? Or a string with a literal backslash followed by an `n`?

Comment: To exclude a file named just `.js` [change the initial `.*` to `.+`](https://regex101.com/r/zG2hI7/3) - Matching across linebreaks is a kind of quirk of using rgex101.com since it seems to lack a mode where each line would be an independent string instead of just part of a large multiline string. If you are not matching in a large multiline string you won't have to worry about this. If you are matching in a multiline text then it gets even trickier and that should be part of your question since it's an important complication.

Comment: `'bla.js\n.js'.match(/.+(?:[^n]|[^i]n|[^b]in|[^.]bin)\.js$/gm)` returns `["bla.js\n.js"]` - it matches over two lines.

Comment: Yes because of the `/gm` flags. I still have no idea if OP needs to deal with filenames such as `'bla.js\n.js'`

Comment: `'bla.js\n.js'.match(/.+(?:[^n]|[^i]n|[^b]in|[^.]bin)\.js$/)` also matches `'bla.js\n.js'` - without any flag. I assume OP doesn't want to deal with such filenames since his reference regex doesn't match them.