# Converting C# delimiters to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a silverlight application that i am converting to html5. I have this piece of code in c# that i am having trouble converting to javascript equivalent.

C#:

```
private const String DELIMITERS = @"(?=[,'\s])|(?<=[,'\s])";
string[] searchList = Regex.Split(MainTextArea.Text, DELIMITERS);
```

This is what i have tried in javascript but it's not splitting text.

javascript:

```
var searchList = $input.val().split("(?=[,'\\s])|(?<=[,'\\s])");
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: That’s because lookbehinds aren’t supported in JS.

Comment: OK so what would be the solution? Is this possible in javascript?

Comment: [Here's an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7376612) that works around javascript not supporting lookbehinds.  Also regular expressions are enclosed between `/` so you'll want to update your javascript to reflect `$input.val().split(/(?=[,'\\s])/);`

Comment: Could you replace each of the delimiters with a single delimiter and then split on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the following ended up being the javascript equivalent:

```
$input.val().split(/([,'\s])+/);
```

Thanks for the helpful comments