# Regex that replace all quotes inside html attributes?

Tags: javascript, regex

Example of string:

```
<a href="#" data-html="<input type="text" data-html="<input type="text">">"></a>
```

The target:

```
<a href="#" data-html="<input type=&quot;text&quot; data-html=&quot;<input type=&quot;text&quot;>&quot;>"></a>
```

I tried:

```
var string = '<a href="#" data-html="<input type="text" data-html="<input type="text">">"></a>';

string.replace(/"+(.?)"+/g, function(s) {
  return '"' + s.slice(1, s.length).slice(0, -1).replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '"';
});
```

Such as I'm noob with regex I need your help :)

P.S. we can't use lookahead & lookbehind (javascript)

Comment: There is lookahead: x(?=y) or lookbehind x(?<=y) in the JavaScript. Not everywhere lookbehind works, so try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative) for alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance I would suggest to use the `escape()` function on the string inside your *data-html=""* value. This handles all conflicting html characters. Then when you read the vale from data-html you can use `unescape()`.

See the following link that explains `escape()` and `unescape()`:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

**Edit:** The `unescape()` function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()` instead: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

Example:

```
var strDataHtml_1 = encodeURI('<input type="text">')
var strDataHtml_2 = encodeURI('<input type="text" data-html="' + strDataHtml_1 + '">');
var string = '<a href="#" data-html="' + strDataHtml_2 + '"></a>';
```

Comment: Erm.. This is not what I was looking for but anyway thanks for your trying.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help, and thanks for returning to let me know :)