# Lookbehind javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace some string using pattern but I have no idea how to check if there is dot before string.
It should be negative for *.some* and positive for *some*

```
var a = "some.string is replaced  and .some.string5 is not"
a.replace(new RegExp("some", "g"), "replaced")
```

It should give result replaced.string is replaced and .some.string5 is not
THX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript regex - look behind alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Javascript hasn't lookbehinds implemented you can match it normally and replace the preceding character with itself with a backreference: `a = a.replace(new RegExp("([^\.]|^)some\.string", "g"), "$1replaced");`

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported in javascript.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of that. I edited my answer.