# RegEx Javascript Positive Lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

so I have been trying to work out how to do an alternate regex match for a Positive Lookbehind in Javascript, I have been trying on and off for 3 days now with no luck, what I want to do works in PHP, but I NEED it to be Javascript.

here is a PHP example of what I want to do: https://regex101.com/r/YpMbI2/5

I usually try to work things out myself, but after 3 days, I kinda need some assistance :D

Thanks in advance for your help :D

Comment: Just replace with `(^|\W)(\s?&gt;)(.+)(?:\n|$)` and manipulate the groups later - what are trying to achieve in the end? Could you provide a minimal example: some input and expected output?

Comment: Javascript regex does not support lookbehind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript regex - look behind alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative)

Comment: @KennethK. I know, this is why I'm asking for help :P I'm trying to figure out a way to do my matches without them

Comment: Ah. I wasn't sure if by "alternate" you meant that or the vertical bars that you have in your pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am coding a BetterDiscord plugin and trying to code in a way to add quotes using `>text`, the example link kinda shows what I'm trying to match and not match, it's kinda hard to show with screenshots

Comment: "To add quotes" means you need to *replace* text. You do not even need a lookbehind here. Just capturing. So, if you need help, please add some simple but comprehensive sample input and expected output *into the question body*. Else, you are the only person who can answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?:^|\W)\s?&gt;(.+)(?:\n|$)
```

since it seems that only the capture group seems to interest you.