# Find all `*.html` but not `*.tmp.html` using JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I have a large project that has many `*.html` files and many `*.tpl.html` files.

I want to use a regular expression that allows me to differentiate between these two for my Webpack config.

I have tried using laziness to achieve this, like `.*?\.html` but this also matches `*.tpl.html`. https://regex101.com/r/a0fl4H/1

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Negative Lookbehind. This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative

Comment: If you use negative lookbehind be sure to select regex Version 2 on regex101

Comment: Do you look for sth like this? [**`^(?!.*\.tpl).*\.html$`**](https://regex101.com/r/a0fl4H/3)

Comment: what if you put  '!*.tpl.html'

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^(?!.*\.tpl).+\.html$
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/a0fl4H/8

Comment: I would use `+` quantifier to prevent the match of `.html` alone.

Comment: I would use `$` anchor to prevent it from matching e.g. `.html.bak`

Comment: @revo Sorry mate. Didn't see your regex in the comments. It got duplicated :(

Answer (score 0):

For regex, this should do it;

`/.*?[^.tpl]\.html/`

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/a0fl4H/2)

**Edit:** This first solution needs improvement. As mentioned in the comments, this will provide false positives for `test.t.html` - as it matches any of the given characters (.tpl).

[This is a working version](https://regex101.com/r/a0fl4H/5) using;

`^(?!.*\.tpl).*.html`

```
bar.html // matches
bar.tpl.html // doesn't match
test.t.html // matches
test.p.html // matches
test.z.html // matches
```

Comment: This would also match something like `a.t.html`.

Comment: `[^.tpl]` doesn't mean anything except `.tpl`,  a sequence of characters.

Comment: @revo - I know, as I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Then you have to update the whole idea behind the answer I think as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @revo - Why don't you enlighten us all with the correct answer, as I'm obviously not working it out for the OP quick enough to satisfy you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134381/discussion-between-thebluefox-and-revo).