# Filter all hashtags found in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create an array with all the hashtags contained in a string. For example:

> Testing #nature #love#instacool#anothertogether #likeforlike, #relax.
>
> multi-line... #festival--
>
> some more text #aaa \n#anotherhashtag

The result would be:

```
["nature", "love", "instacool", "anothertogether", "likeforlike", "relax", "festival", "aaa", "anotherhashtag"]
```

What should be the REGEX for this case? I tried some that I found on the internet but none worked in the given example.

Comment: Does `#festival--` give `"#festival"`, not `"festival"`?

Comment: No, my mistake. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the flag `mg`,
`m` means ‘Multiline’,
`g` means ‘Global search’.

```
`Testing #nature #love#instacool#anothertogether #likeforlike, #relax.

multi-line... #festival--

some more text #aaa \n#anotherhashtag`.match(/#\w+/mg).map(s => s.substr(1))
```

Comment: 1. Javascript doesn't have lookbehinds. You used a negative lookahead. 2. `Testing` should be excluded from your result, as should `multi`, `line`, `some`, `more`, and `text`

Comment: @Gerrit0 I've just got to know the fact haha.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative

Answer (score 4):

Use following approach:

```js
var str = 'Testing #nature #love#instacool#anothertogether #likeforlike, #relax. \nmulti-line... #festival-- some more text #aaa \n#anotherhashtag';

console.log(str.match(/#\w+/g).map(v => v.replace('#', '')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [RegExp#exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). Use the next solution:

```
var str = "Testing #nature #love#instacool#anothertogether #likeforlike, #relax. \n multi-line... #festival-- \nsome more text #aaa \n#anotherhashtag";
var re = /#(\w+)/g;
var res = [];
while (var buf = re.exec(str)) {
  res.push(buf[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```