# Javascript regex: replace an instance in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex in javascript. What I want to do:

1. I want to see if there is an html element with `class=“get-me”` anywhere in the string.
2. If there is I want to replace it with `I found you`.

Examples:

1. `<div class="get-me" />`

Result: `I found you`

2. `<div>Some text <div class="get-me" data-type="data-type" js="js" /> more things happening here</div>`

Result: `<div>Some text I found you more things happening here</div>`

3. `<div>Some text <p class="get-me" /> more things</div>`

Result: `<div>Some text I found you more things</div>`

4. `I m testing <<<<div class="get-me" />`

Result: `I m testing <<<I found you`

Thanks.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761)

Comment: Why have you assumed that I want to be parsing html? I have a specific use case that is not parsing.

Comment: Find a class in an html tag is _parsing_. And for this you could use library such as [sizzlejs](//sizzlejs.com) instead of using regex. Also there is no  lookbehind in javascript, but [there are alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7376238/6320039)

Comment: He probably assumed that you want to parse HTML with regex because that is what you are doing in all of your examples.

Comment: It's not so much an assumption I've made as what you've carefully described above. If you have more context then by all means please [edit] to provide it, but it seems extremely unlikely that regex will be the best tool for the job.

Comment: pattern matching is parsing, and that's what Regex does lol.

Comment: Looks like even though I said I wont be doing any parsing people cannot focus on the pattern. I have edited the question. I hope all of you nice people who couldn't wait to downvote a question, can provide a helpful answer.

Comment: Why do you need a lookbehind or lookahead if you plan on replacing the @ symbols as well? "@getMe@" -> "I found you"

Comment: Good point, lookbehind and lookeahead will not be appropriate here as `@` will remain. However, it will be good to see how to do it only replacing `getMe` within the `@@`. @Funny Geeks, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into the parsing HTML debate, this will answer your original (unedited) question:

```
const replacementText = 'I found you';
const regex = /(.*)<\w+\s.*class="get-me".*\/>(.*)/;
let str = '<div>Some text <div class="get-me" data-type="data-type" js="js" /> more things happening here</div>';
str = str.replace(regex, `$1${replacementText}$2`);
```

Output is

```
"<div>Some text I found you more things happening here</div>"
```

Here is a JSBin for you: https://jsbin.com/rowaxayodu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

This works, finds any tag with *`class="getMe"`* in it.
You can then replace  it with nothing (*remove it from the text*).

*Note that you can't really match a specific tag without matching all tags.

This is because of marks can be embedded inside other tag's, etc...*

`/<[\w:]+(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sclass\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*getMe\s*\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>/`

https://regex101.com/r/PHUrIi/1

Expanded

```
 < [\w:]+               # Any tag

 (?=                    # Assert (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s class  \s* = \s* 
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote
           \s* getMe \s*          # With 'class="getMe"
           \1 
      )
 )
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
 >
```