# javascript regex string with no characters before or after

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to convert "me" to "you", without touching words that have "me" in them, i.e.
"awesome melon me" -> "awesome melon you"

So far I got the negative look ahead pattern:

`str.replace(/me(?![a-zA-Z])/g, 'you')`

so I get

"awesome melon me" -> "awesoyou melon you"

Tried [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative) already, couldn't find someone that matches this request, thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the zero-width `\b` special symbol to ensure to match "me" when it's a complete word:

```
"awesome melon me".replace(/\bme\b/g, "you")
// returns "awesome melon you"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundary as suggested in other answers, which keeps `me345` or `hello_me` as well. If you need a more strict matching pattern, you can capture the matched letter before the pattern, and put it in the replacement pattern.

```js
var s = "me awesome melon me"
console.log(s.replace(/(^|[^a-zA-Z])(me)(?![a-zA-Z])/g, '$1you'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: `str.replace(\bme\b/g, 'you')` - `\b` looks for a word boundary.