# Convert specific regex without negative lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, domain-name

I know there are some answers that help converting negative lookbehind in regex for JS engines prior to ECMA 2018. However, I can't seem to use these hints against my specific regex.

One of these answers: [javascript regex - look behind alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative#answer-7376612)

Here is the original regex (it's my registrar's domain name acceptance regex) :

`^((?!-)[-a-z0-9]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+(?=.{1,63}$)(?!-)([-a-z0-9]*[a-z][-a-z0-9]*\.?)(?<!-)$`

How should I use the combination of supported features in current JS (browsers as of early 2018) to achieve this behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you made a mistake when copying your regex here. `(?!)` will discard any match. Can you describe what this regex is supposed to match and what bot? maybe add a couple of test cases?

Comment: You're right, sorry, some IM programs interpret the hyphen and it disappeared...

Comment: PS : I edited the regex, thank you :)