# Unexpected identifier RegExp Javascript IE

Tags: javascript, regex

the following javascript line is throwing error with the message only on IE:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

```
var result = new RegExp('(?<=\"compliantNotes\": \").*(?=\"\s+\"compliantDetected\":)', 'sgmi').exec(inputString);
```

I created a working copy here: [RegExp Online](https://regex101.com/r/nOE4TJ/2)

The regular expression seems to work fine on Chrome, returning the expected result but I can't figure out why that throws error in IE 11.

Thank you

Comment: Look-behind assertions are not supported in IE, Firefox and many other browsers. Check the browser compatibility in [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thank you @31piy I didn't notice it.. that explains the issue. Is there an alternative way to achieve the same result?

Comment: @31piy I thought it's only *negative* lookbehind that isn't supported in Javascript.

Comment: The google search yielded [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative) as the first result. You should research more, and if it doesn't solve your problem, you should refactor your code or use a different approach altogether.

Comment: @Barmar -- I was not sure of either, so I referenced the MDN docs first, and it reported the compatibility status as _unknown_.

Comment: Thanks @31piy I found that just now. I will do some more research/refactor my code. Question is, why on the website "regex101.com" that same regexp works in IE?

Comment: If you switch to **JavaScript** on regex101 using IE/Edge/Firefox it's not working.

Comment: thanks guys, all clear