# Javascript Regex Negative Lookahead match

Tags: javascript, regex

I suck at regex. I have the following expression:

`(?!.*\")(Level)(\s)([0-9])(?!.*\")`

I want to use this expression to replace all Level 2 to "Level 2" with queries. The problem is that this regex catches `"Level 2`(without closing `"`). I want to catch `Level 2` only if it has to quotes before AND after the words.

What is the best approach to do that?

Comment: Can you add some sample text and actual vs expected output with your current regex?

Comment: Try `(?<=")level\s\d+(?=")`

Comment: I want to replace `Excel Level 2` to `Excel "Level 2"` to refine some search results.

Comment: Try ``.replace(/"[^"]*"|\b(Level\s+\d+)/g, (x,y) => y ? `"${y}"` : x )``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not working. The callback is not called. Is this in the ES5?

Comment: ES5: `s.replace(/"[^"]*"|\b(Level\s+\d+)/g, function(x,y) {return y ? '"' + y + '"' : x; })`

Comment: Not really sure what you need. Probably `s.replace(/(^|[^"])(Level\s+\d+)(?!["\d])/g, '$1"$2"')` is enough.

Comment: I [posted the above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399080/3832970) that will work for all cases when you need to add double quotation marks around `Level <digits>` if it is not already enclosed with double quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to capture every occurrence of `Level\s+\d+` and replace it with `"Level\s+\d+"` provided it is not enclosed by doublequotes from both sides, you may use try using this regex,

```
([^"]|^)(Level\s+\d+)([^"]|$)
```

and replace it with,

```
\1"\2"\3
```

[Check here for a demo](https://regex101.com/r/EJGdZv/1)

This will not choose a text for replacement of type `Label 2"` or `"Label 2` or `"Label 2"` and only replace when `Label 2` when it is not surrounded by double quote from either side.

Comment: Not working ok, because it also replaces `"Level 2"` with `""Level 2""` https://regex101.com/r/kuTf1k/1

Comment: @Filip: Ok I've updated the answer to ensure it is not already surrounded by double quotes. Can you check now?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi You suggest something that only works with ECMAScript 2018 but even [ES6 syntax does not work for OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398711/javascript-regex-negativ-lookahead-match#comment93672805_53398711).

Comment: oh ok Wiktor, sorry I forgot it was javascript where look behind doesn't work :( Let me figure out something else.

Comment: Yeah, I need something that works natively in browser as this is in a simple file not transpilled by babel.

Comment: Ok, I've updated with a regex which doesn't use any look arounds. Let me know if this works fine for you. I've updated the regex101 url to add more cases to show it works in different cases where if Level 2 is at the very start of string or at the very end.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi It won't work in case of `Level 2`s that are consecutive, i.e. that occur after a single char one after another. See [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399080/3832970) that does what you mean to write and is generic (matches any digits after `Level`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Your solution is good but OP really hasn't mentioned anything about whether how to treat this kind of text ("another Level 5") as you have accounted for in your example. With lack of enough samples provided by OP, I would call this post as too broad. May be OP wants to change this string in input "another Level 5" to "another "Level 5"" or may be to this "another "Level 5" which is not clear. I can of course generate a solution for all logically valid cases for OP but due to lack of it, my solution will remain incomplete. Hope OP agrees with your answer and accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```js
var s = '"Level 3 protected": Level 4 here and "another Level 5"';
s = s.replace(/(^|[^"])(Level\s+\d+)(?!["\d])/g, '$1"$2"');
console.log(s);
```

**Details**

- `(^|[^"])` - Group 1 (`$1`): start of string or any char but a double quote
- `(Level\s+\d+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): `Level`, 1+ whitespaces, 1+ digits
- `(?!["\d])` - no digit or double quote to the left of the current location is allowed.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hATzWG/1).

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Not sure if you want to replace `"Level 2` and `Level 2"` or not, so I offer solutions for *both* scenarios:</sup>

**1)** *If you want to replace only those with not even a single `"`:*

`(?<!")(Level\s\d+)(?!")`

see https://regex101.com/r/Nc7b5h/1

This uses a negative look-behind and a negative look-ahead

**2)** *However, if you also want to replace those with only **one** `"`, try this:*

`(?!"Level\s\d+")(?<!")"?Level\s\d+"?`

https://regex101.com/r/qL5Li5/1/

Set your match group based on whether you want to replace the single `"` or not:

```
var s='This "Level 2" is "Level 2 a Level 2" test Level 2 :)'
​
s.replace(/(?!"Level\s\d+")(?<!")"?(Level\s\d+)"?/g, '"$1"');

//> 'This "Level 2" is "Level 2" a "Level 2" test "Level 2" :)'
```

or

```
var s='This "Level 2" is "Level 2 a Level 2" test Level 2 :)'

s.replace(/(?!"Level\s\d+")(?<!")("?Level\s\d+"?)/g, '"$1"');

//> 'This "Level 2" is ""Level 2" a "Level 2"" test "Level 2" :)'
```

The trick here was to first perform a negative look-ahead for the forbidden case of a match with *two* `"`, before doing anything else.

**General Notes**

If you don't want to use a look-behind expression (`(?<!")`) as older browsers (pre-ES2018) won't support that, just use `(^|[^"])` instead, as other suggested. Just don't forget to restore its contents in the replacement :)

e.g. `s.replace(/(?!"Level\s\d+")(^|[^"])"?(Level\s\d+)"?/g, '$1"$2"');`

Comment: [Javascript does not support look behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative).

Comment: @Rahul Actually they are supported since ES 2018 :D

Comment: Is there an official release ?