# What is lookbehind support in JS? How to replace it?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I have a string and I want to replace every 'i' that is NOT following/followed by any other i and replace it with 'z`. I know that there is negative lookahead and lookbehind.

Results shoud be:

```
i => z
iki => zkz
iiki => iikz
ii => ii
iii => iii
```

I tried to use this:

```
/(?<!i)i(?!i)/gi
```

and it failed and thrown an error: `Invalid regex group`.

Yet

```
/i(?!i)/gi
```

works fine, but matches second "i" in this: "ii".

Is there some other way?

What is support for lookbehind in JS if there is any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case you don't really need look-behind:

```
'iiki'.replace(/i+/g, (m0) => m0.length > 1 ? m0 : 'z')
```

You can just use a function as the replacement part and test the length of the matched string.

Here are all your test cases:

```js
function test(input, expect) {
  const result = input.replace(/i+/g, (m0) => m0.length > 1 ? m0 : 'z');
  console.log(input + " => " + result + " // " + (result === expect ? "Good" : "ERROR"));
}

test('i', 'z');
test('iki', 'zkz');
test('iiki', 'iikz');
test('ii', 'ii');
test('iii', 'iii');
```

Answer (score 5):

Lookbehind in JavaScript regular expressions is quite new. As of this writing, it's [only supported in V8](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions) (in Chrome, Chromium, Brave...), not by other engines.

There are [many questions with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D%20alternative%20for%20lookbehind) here about how to work around not having lookbehind, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative).

[This article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) by Steven Levithan also shows ways to work around the absense of the feature.

> I want to replace every 'i' that is NOT following/followed by any other i and replace it with 'z`

That's fairly easy to do without either lookahead or lookbehind, using placeholders and a capture group. You can capture what follows the `i`:

```
const rex = /i(i+|.|$)/g;
```

...and then conditionally replace it if what was captured isn't an `i` or series of `i`s:

```
const result = input.replace(rex, (m, c) => {
    return c[0] === "i" ? m : "z" + c;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const rex = /i(i+|.|$)/g;
function test(input, expect) {
    const result = input.replace(rex, (m, c) => {
        return c[0] === "i" ? m : "z" + c;
    });
    console.log(input, result, result === expect ? "Good" : "ERROR");
}

test("i", "z");
test("iki", "zkz");
test("iiki", "iikz");
test("ii", "ii");
test("iii", "iii");
```

Answer (score 1):

One hack you can use in this case. is changing the offset value based on match.

```js
let arr = ['i','iki','iiki','ii','iii', 'ki']

arr.forEach(e=>{
  let value = e.replace(/i(?!i)/g, function(match,offset,string){
    return offset > 0 && string[offset-1] === 'i' ? 'i' : 'z'
  })
  console.log(value)
})
```