# Regex to match/replace leading tabs without lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

I am trying to match each `\t` in the leading whitespace of a line so I can replace them with two spaces.  This is trivial with an unbounded (i.e., variable-length) lookbehind.

```js
text.replace(/(?<=^\s*)\t/gm, '  ')
```

Unfortunately, this code is running on iOS, and for some reason, Safari and iOS have [yet to implement lookbehinds](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), let alone unbounded lookbehinds.

I know there are [workarounds for lookbehinds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7376612/3120446), but I can't seem to get the ones I've looked at to work.

I would rather not capture any characters aside from each tab, but if there's no other way, I could capture characters around the tabs in capture groups and add `$1`, etc, to my replacement string.

##### Example test code

```js
const text = `
\t\ta
  \t  b
 \t  \t c\td  \te
`

const expected = `
    a
      b
        c\td  \te
`

// throws error in iOS, which does not support lookbehinds
// const regex = /(?<=^\s*)\t/gm;
const regex = /to-do/gm;

const result = text.replace(regex, '  ')

console.log(`Text: ${text}`)
console.log(`Expected: ${expected}`)
console.log(`Result: ${result}`)
console.log(JSON.stringify([ expected, result ], null, 2))

if (result === expected) {
  console.info('Success! ')
} else {
  console.error('Failed ')
}
```

**Update**

A less than ideal workaround would be to use two regexes and a replacer function.

```js
const text = `
\t\ta
  \t  b
 \t  \t c\td  \te
`

const expected = `
    a
      b
        c\td  \te
`

const result = text.replace(/^\s*/gm, m => m.replace(/\t/g, '  '))

if (result === expected) {
  console.info('Success! ')
} else {
  console.error('Failed ')
}
```

Again, less than ideal.  I'm a purist.

Comment: Since there is no look around in your platform, it can't be done with a single regex.  Otherwise you wouldn't even need a variable length look behind. This is simple enough to work on all platforms [/(?:(?<!\[^\t\])|^)(\[^\S\r\n\t\]*)\t/gm](https://regex101.com/r/lFMD0w/1) replace with `$1  ` Except if your working on a real brezerk one.

Comment: @sln There's lookahead, just no lookbehind.

Comment: But since the engine is free to advance to any position, there is no solution, right ? No single regex solution exists then.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this Javascript solution without involving looknbehind:

```js
const text = `
\t\ta
  \t  b
 \t  \t c\td  \te
`;

var repl = text.replace(/^[ \t]+/mg, g => g.replace(/\t/g, '  '));

console.log(repl);
```

Comment: So, exactly what I did in my update?  ;)  This question is more for my edification than needing an answer that works, so I'd like to do it in a single regex.

Comment: I was just reading the updated section. Sorry I started writing answer with the original question. It is unlikely that the a solution can be found without lookbehind and without a replacer lambda/function

Comment: Unfortunately Javascript doesn't support `\G` otherwise in PCRE/Java it would be been `.replaceAll("(^ *|(?!^)\\G)\t", "$1. ");`

Comment: No worries about starting your answer before reading my edit.  I assumed that's what happened. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Ruby solution, should a reader wish to post a Javascript solution based on it.

```
rgx = /[a-z].*|\t/
str.gsub(rgx) { |s| s[0] == "\t" ? '  ' : s }
```

where `str` holds the string that is to be modified.

The regular expression is a two-part alternation:

```
[a-z]  # match a lower-case letter
.*     # match zero or more characters (to end of string)
|      # or
\t     # match a tab
```

Each match is passed to the "block" (`{ |s| ...}`) and is held by the block variable `s`. If the first character of the match is a tab two spaces are returned; else `s` is returned. If `[a-z].*` is matched there will be no further matches because the remainder of the string (possibly including tabs) will have been consumed.

In Python a lambda would by used in place of Ruby's block, something like

```
lambda m: '  ' if m.group()[0] == "\t" else m.group()
```

Comment: Pythonites: If the lambda I presented is incorrect I would be grateful for a correction in a comment.