# Javascript object keys with spaces

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm playing around with the vue.js library, and I'm trying to make a change to the grid component example located here: http://vuejs.org/examples/grid-component.html

The sorting breaks when I add a space to one of the column names. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/greene48/9d1f0858/

The column name gets passed through the sortBy function, which updates the sortKey variable to be the column name, and toggles the appropriate sortOrders key to be either -1 or 1.

```
sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? When I check the value of sortKey and sortOrders[key] they seem to be updating correctly. I think it must have something to do with not being able to use a space in the built in Vue.js orderBy filter. So it must break here:

```
<tr v-for="entry in data | filterBy filterKey | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
</tr>
```

But I don't see anything in the Vue.js docs on how to fix this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is there any good reason for using a property name with spaces? Why not just use a `name_with_underscore` or `camelCase`?

Comment: Well I wanted the column header name to have a space. But I suppose I could store the column header names in a separate object and access them using name_with_underscore as the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy fix would be to replace key `power value` with `power_value` and then change the header manually after the Vue rendering using pure javascript like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('#demo thead th')[1].textContent = 'Power value';
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9d1f0858/1/)

Comment: This works, thanks. I guess like codejak suggested I shouldn't be using property names with spaces, it makes more sense to name them properly and then worry about how to display them after.

Answer (score 2):

You should surround the `sortKey` with square brackets,

```
orderBy [sortKey] sortOrders[sortKey]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9d1f0858/2/

However, I agree to the above said to avoid to use property names with whitespaces.

Comment: The direction functionality is not working. It seems like the brackets notation in vue's expressions only works for variables, as opposed to properties.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not making your property names dependent on the way you want them presented in your front end.

Use names that do not cause these issues as I suggested in my comment.

Your thought of mapping these names to an output value sounds reasonable.

You could even go as far as looking into the approaches described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225407/convert-camelcasetext-to-camel-case-text). Though that already creates constraints again.

Comment: Thanks, you're right it makes more sense to name them properly. I think I will either store them in a separate array, or change the output using javascript like Almis suggested.