# insert space before capital letters - knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have an observable which has the value like this `firstName` or `firstNameText`

When I am displaying it, how can I add space before the capital letters.

> `firstname` will be `First Name` and `firstNameText` will be `First Name Text`

```
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
```

I need to do it in the HTML itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert camelCaseText to Camel Case Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225407/convert-camelcasetext-to-camel-case-text)

Answer (score 0):

```
text: name()
.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
.replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); })
// you could add plain javascript expressions in the text binding but you have to call the observable to get the value
```