# Display key name with spaces in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

repeat where i am repeating key value pairs, I am having key without spaces where i need to display with space.

my ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject"
```

i am displaying in span:

```
<span class="accordion-title">
       {{key}}
 </span>
```

in controller i am pushing the array as :

```
 vm.shared.collectionFlyoutObject.BusinessDrivers.push(data);
```

Its working fine and displaying key as BusinessDrivers.
But i need to display as Business Drivers .

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225407/convert-camelcasetext-to-camel-case-text

Comment: any example can you provide?

Comment: we can create a filter that turn it in to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to somehow work with the current key and add spaces to it the way you want.  One alternative would be to just maintain state in the collection book object for the human readable form of the key.  Assuming such a field `keyView` existed, then you would access it on the `value`, not the `key`, using this:

```
<span class="accordion-title">
    {{value.keyView}}
</span>
```

Another approach would be to just maintain a map in your controller which can map the keys to the human readable forms you want, e.g.

```
$scope.keyViews = { };
$scope.keyViews['BusinessDrivers'] = 'Business Drivers';
```

And then display using this:

```
<span class="accordion-title">
    {{keyViews[key]}}
</span>
```

But this approach is less nice than keeping all the relevant state in a single map, for maintenance and other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function to split camelCase. You just have to define the function in your main controller and it can be referenced anywhere in your code.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {
$scope.splitCamelCase = function(input) {
    if (!input)
        return;
    var j = 0;
    var splitString = "";
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
            splitString = splitString + " " + input.slice(j, i);
            j = i;
        }
    }
    splitString = splitString + " " + input.slice(j, i);
    return splitString.replace("And", "and").replace("and", " and").substr(1, splitString.length);
};
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ApplicationController">
        <div class="row">
        {{splitCamelCase("BusinessDrivers")}}
       </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myFormat', function() {
    return function(x) {
        var txt = x.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, "$1").replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g, " $1")
        return txt;
    };
});
```

we can make a filter to create the effect.
in template

```
<span class="accordion-title">
       {{key | myFormat}}
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am copied the snippet from @Vivz  to make my change

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {
 $scope.splitCamelCase = function(input) {
  return  input.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1").replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g, " $1");

 };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ApplicationController">
        <div class="row">
        {{splitCamelCase("BusinessDrivers")}}
       </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to convert the key from camelCase to a space separated proper string, then I suggest you to use a filter as that would be the easiest way.

You can simply create a new filter and use that.

controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.filter('splitCamelCase', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substr(1).replace(/[A-Z]/g, ' $&');
  }
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{str | splitCamelCase }}
</div>
```

This is just an example. Hope this helps :) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cz62udv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers above is a little bit overwhelming. It can all be narrowed down to :

```js
.filter('splitByUppercase', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ')
  }
})
```

Example

```html
<span ng-repeat="t in test">
   {{ t | splitByUppercase }}<br>
</span>
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/OUfmusiswNeEpSURFVRx?p=preview**

If you want to lowercase the extracted words so it becomes "Business drivers" etc you can use

```
.filter('splitByUppercase', function() {
    return function(input) {
      input = input.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
      input = input.map(function(s,i) {
        if (i>0) s = s[0].toLowerCase() + s.substring(1)
        return s
      });
      return input.join(' ')
    }
 })
```