# How to cut one string to sententce and capitalize each letter of words

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript. I have a little problem:

I have a string like this "thisIsATestString".

So how can I make this string to "This Is A Test String"?

Comment: well? what have you tried?

Comment: you can detect for the pattern <lowecase><Uppercase> and then insert a whitespace between them

Comment: thanks, I can done it now

Answer (score 0):

Already answered: [Convert camelCaseText to Sentence Case Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225407/convert-camelcasetext-to-sentence-case-text)

You should have searched for "camel case to sentence."

Answer (score -1):

This should help to resolve it.

```
const sentence  = 'thisIsATestString';
const updatedSentenec = (sentence[0].toUpperCase() + sentence.slice(1)).split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ')
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
"thisIsATestString".replace(/(^\w|[A-Z])/g, function (match) {
    return ' ' + match.toUpperCase();
}).trim();
```